# Javascript method CalculateCost() Not returning any values for me

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

I have a .js file that contains a constructor for a class called PortraitOrder(). It has a method named CalculateCost(). For some reason when I call for the CalculateCost() method later on, nothing happens.

1. Here is PortraitOrder() and CalculateCost()

   ```
    function PortraitOrder(portrait, copies, size, buyer){

                this.portrait = portrait;
                this.copies = copies;
                this.size = size;
                this.buyer = buyer;

                function CalculateCost(){

                this.size = size;

                this.copies = copies;

                var price;

                if(size == "wallet"){

                     price = 10;

                }
                else if(size == "8x10"){

                     price = 10;

                }
                else if(size == "4x6"){

                     price = 10;

                }
                else if(size == "11x14"){

                     price = 30;

                }
                else{

                     price = 10;

                }

                var cost = price * copies;

                return cost;

                }

       }
   ```
2. Here is how I call the method

   ```
        var cost = CalculateCost().toFixed(2);

           document.write("Price of Order: " + cost + "<br/>");
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what seems to be a scoping issue. `CalculateCost()` is a function declared within the `PortraitOrder()` function, so it will not be accessible outside that function. Try moving the CalculateCost() function outside of PortraitOrder(), and pass the required variables as parameters, like so:

```
function PortraitOrder() {
  ....
}

function CalculateCost(price, copies) {
  ....
}
```

Then, you can call CalculateCost() as:

```
CalculateCost(price, copies);
```

If you do wish to have CalculateCost() available as part of PortraitOrder(), you can do so by keeping a reference to it in a variable.

**Update:** From your comments below, you said you wish to create an object with member variables and functions. Here are some useful links:

- [JavaScript objects primer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
- [Member functions](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0500__Object-Oriented/0080__Member-Function.htm)
- [An example of object members](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0500__Object-Oriented/CreateanObjectwithmembermethod.htm)
- [A more complete example](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/class-member-encapsulation-in-javascript-data-hiding.html)
- [A relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700273/declaring-a-member-function-in-js)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's part of an assignment. I'm supposed to have it inside portraitorder()

Comment: Ah, you wish to set it as a member function. You did not specify that in the question (or at least it wasn't obvious from your code). You can do PortraitOrder.prototype.calculateCost = function() { }

Comment: Oh ok. If that's the case, are my variable declarations correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm updating my answer with some links

Comment: Hmmmm. it still isnt showing anything. I changed the function to a prototype as you said

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to define methods in javascript. You should define your function like this:

```
function PortraitOrder (parameters) {
    //Constructor
}

PortraitOrder.prototype.calculateCost = function () {
    //Your cost function
};
```

Also, a nice introduction to OOP in Javascript can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript