# Create Javascript library not working

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
(function(window, myObj) {
  window.onload = myObj.onload;
})(window, function() {
  this.onload = function() {
    console.log('Loading...');
  };
});
```

But it not working, when load page, nothing in web console. Somebody help me!!! Thank so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700273/declaring-a-member-function-in-js

Answer (score 0):

Let's separate out the functions.

```
var myFunc = function() {
  this.onload = function() {
    console.log('Loading...');
  };
};
(function(window, myObj) {
  window.onload = myObj.onload;
})(window, myFunc);
```

As we can see `myFunc` don't have method `onload` which we are trying to use on `window.onload = myObj.onload`

Either we can use

```
(function(window, myObj) {
     window.onload = myObj.onload;
   })(window, new myFunc()); // here myObj.onload will be availabel
```

Or we can have `static` method for `onload` defined in `myFunc`

```
var myFunc = function() {
};
myFunc.onload = function() {
    console.log('Loading...');
};
(function(window, myObj) {
  window.onload = myObj.onload;
})(window, myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function what you pass into is not an object. So it won't have onload method.You can use the `new` operator to create a object.

```js
function Fun(){
  this.onload = function() {
    console.log( 'Loading....' );
  }
}
(function( window, myObj ){
  window.onload = myObj.onload;  
})( window, new Fun() );
```